# how to query below document to find all ev=1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to query below document to find all ev of email_info subset

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e13dc9abdb1c233db92dff"), 
    "customer_id" : NumberInt(8383), 
    "customerdetails" : {
        "name" : "Myth 2016", 
        "email_info" : {
            "email" : "myth1926@gmail.com", 
            "ev" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        "mobile_userid" : "3#102103293090775998087", 
        "usertype" : "non-anon", 
        "loginmode" : "GooglePlus"
    }
}
```

i am using

```
db.customer_detail.find({"email_info.ev":1});
```

but it is not giving me result.

Answer (score 4):

You must include all the path:

```
db.customer_detail.find({"customerdetails.email_info.ev":1});
```

Comment: @jackSparrow if the answer suits you, I invite you to make it "accepted" for further searches. :)